# In asp.net RequiredFieldValidator What is difference between Text and ErrorMessage?

Tags: asp.net, validation

In asp.net RequiredFieldValidator What is difference between Text and ErrorMessage property?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Text :** The message to display when validation fails.

**ErrorMessage :** The text to display in the ValidationSummary control when validation fails. Note: This text will also be displayed in the validation control if the Text property is not set.

Ref : http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_reqfieldvalidator.asp

Answer (score 8):

The ErrorMessage property shows up in the ValidationSummary control. Text shows up next to the controlToValidate. If you set the Display property as None the Text won't appear.

Answer (score 2):

In a normal setup, the text property is displayed next to the validator and the error message is displayed in the ValidationSummary.

Answer (score 1):

Text and ErrorMessage are both used to display error message.
But remember that if you are using Text property then in validation summary nothing will be displayed.
To display your errors in validationSummary in is compulsory to use ErrorMessage.
If u want to display error message infront of textbox then both works same.
And if you are using both then in Text has precedence in displaying error message infront of text message.